# Silex routing isn't working

Tags: routes, url-routing, silex

I'm working on a Silex project and I am having trouble with routes.

This works:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array());
})
->bind('homepage');
```

But this does not:

```
$app->get('/contact', function () use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('contact.html', array());
})
->bind('contact');
```

Apache said: Not Found!!!, I don't know why the first one works but not the second.

Any ideas??

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled and configured to route 404's to silex? The fact that you got an apache 404 suggests otherwise.

Comment: What is the URL you're entering?

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled and the URL http://localhost/web/contact

Comment: try http://localhost/contact - your route is set up for that URL, not web/contact. The routes are all relative to the base URL (in this case, localhost).

Comment: localhost/contact not work but I try localhost/web/index.php/contact and it works. How I can avoid index.php?

Comment: Did you follow the guide here: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html for .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`.